# Format Number without using FORMAT()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

Trying to format the number(Amount) as per the given currency pattern and culture.

Given:

```
-4059587.225000, --Amount
'#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)' --Pattern
'en-US' --Culture
```

Will have many patterns, the given one is for example.

Expected output: `(4,059,587.23)`

My try:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CAST(-4059587.225000 AS money), 1);
```

Output: `-4,059,587.23`

Comment: If you want to use a pattern and culture then [format()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) is actually the tool you want. Unless you mess around with SQL CLR and use .NET's format which is effectively the same.

Comment: Honestly, *formatting* the value is normally a task for the presentation layer, *not* the SQL layer.

Comment: @Larnu I remember (years ago) when `FORMAT` (and `TRY_PARSE`) were new that they _really were_ just wrappers over CLR's formatting and parsing functions which made them kinda expensive to use in queries compared to the native `CONVERT()` function (when used with the `style` param). Do you know if this is still the case?

Comment: The implement is still the same, @Dai , even it 2022 (as far as I'm aware).

Comment: Sure? because it feels a lot faster nowadays, and it also works in Azure SQL which has SQLCLR completely disabled.

Comment: Yes, @Dai. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks): *"FORMAT relies on the presence of the .NET Framework Common Language Runtime (CLR). This function cannot be remoted since it depends on the presence of the CLR. Remoting a function that requires the CLR, could cause an error on the remote server. FORMAT relies upon CLR formatting rules, which dictate that colons and periods must be escaped."*